# How do I read a configuration parameter or file in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to read - in an Angular Service Class(TypeScript) - a configuration file with a base URL of a web service I consume data from.

It is just an Ajax call with a HttpClient, but I am new to angular.

I serve my app from a **Node.js** server.

This baseUrl changes and that's why it needs to be configured. In fact, I also wanted to check if it is possible to define the base Url as a start up parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file called `app.config.ts` - name can be up to you, like below:

```
export interface ApplicationConfig {
  apiURL: string;
}

export const CONFIG: ApplicationConfig = {
  apiURL: 'url to your server';
};
```

Inside your service, import that file and use it like so:

```
import { CONFIG } from '../config/app.config';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  private baseURL: string = CONFIG.apiURL;

  constructor(private http: Http){}

  public getSomething():Observable<any> {
    let url:string = this.baseUrl + 'endpoint url after the base url';

    return this.http.get(url).map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can pass the url as some sort of a parameter at start up

Comment: There is a way to do that, with a combination of the node process parameters and the webpack define plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base file to export your endpoint, so for example your base.ts should be something like :

```
export const baseUrl = 'http://yourendpoint.com';
```

so then in your component or your service you can use it like :

```
import {baseUrl} from './base'; //path to base.ts
...
console.log(baseUrl);//http://yourendpoint.com
```

Answer (score -2):

You can read a very comprehensive tutorial at the angular website. Here you can learn all the basics you need: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: Hi, can you point me to the part where they talk the configuration part. I did not find it.

Comment: Also, I am using httpclient, slightly different from this tutorial